pandas pivot data, fill Mult index column horizontally
i have the following code:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'name': ['Comp1', 'Comp1', 'Comp2', 'Comp2', 'Comp3'],
    'entity_type': ['type1', 'type1', 'type2', 'type2', 'type3'],
    'code': ['code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code1', 'code2'],
    'date': ['2024-01-31', '2024-01-31', '2024-01-29', '2024-01-31', '2024-01-29'],
    'value': [10, 10, 100, 10, 200],
    'source': [None, None, 'Estimated', None, 'Reported']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pivot_df = df.pivot(index='date', columns=['name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'code'], values='value').rename_axis([('name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'date')])
df = pivot_df.reset_index()
df

This produces the following:

I am having trouble with the following:

I would like to remove the first column
I would like to fill the first 3 rows horizontally. so, for example, the blank cells above 'code2' should be Comp1, type1, NaN
would be nice to replace those nans in the column headers with empty string

Any help would be appreciated.
EDIT - working hack
as this data i want to end up as an array that looks exactly like it does in the dataframe to insert into a spreadsheet..this works. In this case however, there would not be any meaningful 'columns'..
out = (df.pivot(index='date', columns=['name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'code'], values='value')
         .rename_axis([('name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'date')])
         .reset_index()
         .fillna('')
      )
out.columns.names = [None, None, None, None]
columns_df = pd.DataFrame(out.columns.tolist()).T
out = pd.concat([columns_df, pd.DataFrame(out.values)], ignore_index=True)
out


You could (1) reset_index with drop=True, (2) set the display.multi_sparse to False (with pandas.option_context) and (3) fillna with '':
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = (df.pivot(index='date', columns=['name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'code'],
                values='value')
         .rename_axis([('name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'date')])
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         .fillna('')
      )

with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(out)

Output:
name        Comp1 Comp1     Comp2 Comp2    Comp3
entity_type type1 type1     type2 type2    type3
source        NaN   NaN Estimated   NaN Reported
code        code1 code2     code3 code1    code2
0                           100.0          200.0
1            10.0  10.0            10.0         

Printing without the index:
out = (df.pivot(index='date', columns=['name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'code'],
                values='value')
         .fillna('')
      )

with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(out.to_string(index=False))

Output:
Comp1 Comp1     Comp2 Comp2    Comp3
type1 type1     type2 type2    type3
  NaN   NaN Estimated   NaN Reported
code1 code2     code3 code1    code2
                100.0          200.0
 10.0  10.0            10.0         

Hiding the indices:
out = (df.pivot(index='date', columns=['name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'code'],
                values='value')
         .rename_axis(None)
         .rename(lambda x: '')
         .fillna('')
      )

with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(out)

Output:
name        Comp1 Comp1     Comp2 Comp2    Comp3
entity_type type1 type1     type2 type2    type3
source        NaN   NaN Estimated   NaN Reported
code        code1 code2     code3 code1    code2
                            100.0          200.0
             10.0  10.0            10.0         

Updated answer: header as rows
out = (df.pivot(index='date', columns=['name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'code'],
                values='value')
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=('name', 'entity_type', 'source', 'date'))
         .fillna('')
         .T.reset_index().T
         .reset_index()
      )

Output:
         index      0      1          2      3         4
0         name  Comp1  Comp1      Comp2  Comp2     Comp3
1  entity_type  type1  type1      type2  type2     type3
2       source    NaN    NaN  Estimated    NaN  Reported
3         date  code1  code2      code3  code1     code2
4   2024-01-29                    100.0            200.0
5   2024-01-31   10.0   10.0              10.0          


thank you. this is close. but the column that is dropped is the 2nd column not the first it appears.  there is no dates as you can see from your output. also the fillna is applied to the values, not those nans in the header

it looksl ike if i remove the drop=True for reset_index and do pivot_df.columns.names = [None, None, None, None]
if you can update your answer w/ that bit i will mark as the solution.
also if you know how to fill those NAN in the columns (not value) that would be great.

darn..without the rest_index(drop=true) however, doesnt seem to fill horizontally. feels like back to square one...the filling seems more a function of print than the dataframe.

@mike01010 this removed the first column. I believe you want to remove the index. In this case, skip the reset_index and print without the index (see update)

thatks much @mozway. truly appreciated.  i do want the dates in there though.  I have come up with hacky way of doing it..but it works for me since i want to basically return the data to be layed out exactly as is in the dataframe in an excel spreadsheet.  I will post and edit for you to see and tell me how terrible it is...

@mike01010 can you provide the exact expected output in your question? That would be more explicit

@mike01010 I see now, check the update.

excellent! thank you
